# Impossible to reach TextView from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I encounter some issue with getting the reference to a Texview inside a Fragment, and I really have no idea why.

Here is my **layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvLogout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSettings"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the **Java Class**

```
public class TabPersonnalSpace extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_personnal_space, container, false);

        TextView tvSettings = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSettings);
        Log.d("Debug", tvSettings.getText().toString());

        tvSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Thing is : I get the text printed to the logcat when `swipe` to the Fragment, and **nothing** happened when I click on the TextView.

Does anyone have a clue for me?

Comment: show show show!(add toast.show()) and also check your id and how have you not gotten NPE?

Comment: @Droidekas : Indeed, show was the cause root...

Comment: But the IDEs now days usually list such issues.Surprised you didnt notice a lint error.But nonetheless its a common error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget .`show()` to display `Toast`

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @M D My bad, bad copy/paste. I indeed have a @+id/tvSettings TextView, see edited post.

Comment: @Mornor also called `.show();` if you want to see `Toast` message.

Comment: @Mornor Now check my answer and make sure you've right Id.

Comment: @M D : One hour of lost in my coding day for this... Huge thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71325/discussion-between-m-d-and-mornor).

Answer (score 0):

implement onViewCreated like this :

```
  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //instantiate tvSettings 
        TextView tvSettings = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSettings);
    }
```